# JsonConstructor throws Exception even when the passed parameter is not null

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following constructors, one for the default and the other for the `Json Deserialization`

```
public Truck(string maker, string model, int relYear, 
            int purcYear,bool isSold,int wheels, int miles)
            :this(maker,model,relYear,purcYear,wheels,miles)
       
        {

            IsSold = isSold;
        }
```

this is for the `Json`

```
 [JsonConstructor]
        public Truck(string maker, string model, int relYear, 
            int purcYear, int wheels, int miles)

        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(maker)) 
                throw new ArgumentException("Manufacture cann't be empty", nameof(maker));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model)) 
                throw new ArgumentException("model cann't be empty", nameof(model));
            if (relYear < 0 || purcYear < 0) 
                throw new ArgumentException("Years are not negative values");

            Manufacturer = maker;
            Model = model;
            PurchaseYear = purcYear;
            ReleaseYear = relYear;
            Wheels = wheels;
            Miles = miles;

        }
```

In my main a have an array of the different `Ivehicle` types. When i serialize the the first Truck it works ok, but when i deserialize it, it doesn't work and throws an `Exception` for the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` but the `maker` is not null at this moment.

I am missing something here or allowing the `default constructor` to call the `Jsonconstructor` is calling this problem?

One thing is when i remove the the if block `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(maker)` then it works fine without throwing an exception

### Main here

```
var vehls = new IVehicle[]
            {
                new Truck("Ford", "F15000", 2011, 2016,true,8,23000),
                new Truck("Ford", "F-150", 2009, 2014,false,8,13000),
                new Car(4,13000,"Ford", "Super Duty")
            };

string sl = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vehls[0],Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(sl);

            var tk = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Truck>(sl);
            Console.WriteLine(tk.Manufacturer);
```

Comment: Can you extend your question to a full [mcve]?  There are several possible problems but we can't say for certain which it is without seeing the `Truck` type.

Comment: @dbc do you mean the class? i have a Verhicle Interface that for implementing all the properties. I can post it if that i want you mean.

Comment: I mean a [mcve] - sufficient code for us to paste into a visual studio console app and reproduce and debug the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that your constructor parameter names do not match your property names.  When Json.NET uses a non-default constructor it matches the JSON property names to constructor arguments by doing a case-independent string match.  If no match is found a default value is passed, which triggers your `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` check.

Thus your constructor needs to look like:

```
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Truck(string manufacturer, string model, int releaseYear,
        int purchaseYear, int wheels, int miles)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(manufacturer))
            throw new ArgumentException("Manufacture can't be empty", nameof(manufacturer));
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model))
            throw new ArgumentException("model can't be empty", nameof(model));
        if (releaseYear < 0 || purchaseYear < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Years are not negative values");

        this.Manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.Model = model;
        this.PurchaseYear = purchaseYear;
        this.ReleaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.Wheels = wheels;
        this.Miles = miles;
    }
```

If no match is found for a constructor argument but a match is found for a read/write member, the member will be set later.  This explains why your code works after you remove the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` check.

Comment: @dbc: Nice catch :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified the TypeNameHandling when you write and read your structures? Usually that's what you need when you serialize something whose runtime type (`Car`, `Truck`) is different from the compile time time (`IVehicle`). This will take car of the inheritance (or in your case, the interface implementation issues).

See documentation:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm